# How to add header title next to logo in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code,

```
    <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/sjco0mvjz/home_slider1.jpg" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/7p0bit16n/home_slider2.jpg" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/6lg76ugjj/home_slider3.jpg" /></a>

    </div>
       <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://s17.postimg.org/mh51a573z/home_slider4.jpg" /></a>

    </div>
  </div>


</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-inner"> <!--changes made here-->
    <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/5qb3lvxsn/logo_new.png" alt="">
            </a>   
    </div>
</div>
</nav>



    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

I need something like this, [image](http://s22.postimg.org/mutgdq6pd/untitled.png)

May i know, the title "Live Safely with AlertID " to display next to logo..

Which bootstrap class should i use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use <p> Live Safely.....</p> tag for text on the image.
you just have to change the style of the <p> tag something like this.

position:absolute;
margin-left: your_requirement;
margin-top: your_requirement;

and you can add many more according to your requirements.
```

Comment: I need something like bootstrap.. so i need to add bootstrap classes.. thanks

Comment: you can use bootstrap inbuild classes for text like "center" it will automaticaly centered your text.

Comment: you  can do this using bootstrap boxing modal...for now i have done using myStyleSheet. you can see for reffernce.     https://jsfiddle.net/qm50zjvz/